# Как взять всех прямых потомков у e.target?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь вычислить высоту блока, что бы сделать плавную анимацию. Подскажите как правильно узнать количество потомков **li** в текущем **ul** ? Пытасю так **let length = e.target.childNodes.length;** но почему-то возвращает 19 вместо 9-ти.

**https://codepen.io/pen/**

```js
let formStep3 = document.querySelector('#step3');

formStep3.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('optionList-active')){
        e.target.classList.remove('optionList-active');
                e.target.style.height = "40px";
  } else if (e.target.classList.contains('optionList')){
        e.target.classList.add('optionList-active');
        // e.target.style.height = "100%";
   let length = e.target.childNodes.length;
    e.target.style.height = length*36+'px' ;
    alert(length);
  }
});
```

```css
.optionList{
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(161,161,161,1) 0%, rgba(29,86,133,1) 0%, rgba(0,52,82,1) 100%, rgba(0,142,255,1) 100%);
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.optionList-active{
/*     height: 100%; */
}
.optionList:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(../img/configurator/arrowWhite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;

}

.configurator-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 673px;
  background-color: #03617f;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.configurator-button:hover {
  background-color: #059DC3;
}


#step3 {
    max-height: 260px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
              <form class="configurator-form-1" id="step3">
                <ul class="optionList">Установка тахографа
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
                    <li class="configurator-button" >Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
                                      <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
                    <li class="configurator-button" >Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
                                      <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
                    <li class="configurator-button" >Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="optionList">Установка тахографа 2
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
                    <li class="configurator-button" >Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="optionList">Установка тахографа 2
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
                    <li class="configurator-button" >Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="optionList">Установка тахографа
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
                    <li class="configurator-button" >Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="optionList">Установка тахографа 2
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
                    <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
                    <li class="configurator-button" >Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
                </ul>
              </form>
```

CODPEN**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `childNodes` используйте `children`

Answer (score 1):

В коллекции, возвращаемой свойством [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), содержатся все дочерние узлы, включая текстовые.

Для получения только элементов можно воспользоваться свойством [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

Либо воспользоваться выборкой с помощью `.querySelectorAll`

```js
let ol = document.querySelector('.optionList');

console.log(ol.childNodes.length);
console.log(ol.children.length);
console.log(ol.querySelectorAll(':scope > li').length); // не работает в IE/EDGE
```

```css
.optionList {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(161, 161, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(29, 86, 133, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 52, 82, 1) 100%, rgba(0, 142, 255, 1) 100%);
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.optionList-active {
  /*     height: 100%; */
}

.optionList:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(../img/configurator/arrowWhite.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.configurator-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 673px;
  background-color: #03617f;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.configurator-button:hover {
  background-color: #059DC3;
}

#step3 {
  max-height: 260px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="optionList">Установка тахографа
  <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
  <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
  <li class="configurator-button">Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
  <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
  <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
  <li class="configurator-button">Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
  <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Тахограф (эксплуатация по </li>
  <li class="configurator-button configOptions">Установка цифрового тахогр</li>
  <li class="configurator-button">Установка цифрового тахографа </li>
</ul>
```